# Getting the current value of a textbox in Access 2013 Custom Web App

Tags: ms-access-2013

in a List view I want a particular control (textbox) to have a red background color if it has a certain value. I have tried the following:

Click on the textbox then click the Data icon in the context sensitive controls that appear. I can then see that the name of the control is First_NameTextBox. I then click anywhere on the List view and click the Actions icon in the context controls that appear to the right of the view. I select "On Current". I then create two steps that should be executed whenever a new record is activated:

```
If [First_NameTextBox] = "somevalue" Then
    SetProperty
        Control Name     [First_NameTextBox]
        Property            BackColor
        Value                #FF0000
End If
```

However, this turns the textbox red no matter what the value in First_NameTextBox is. How do I reference the CURRENT value of the textbox?

Answer (score 0):

Conditional formatting based on a field value is not available for the List View in a Web App.

If you've built web pages (with or without a templating engine), the design limitations of Access can be frustrating.

Another kind of frustration comes from moving a form in Access from the native Access environment to a browser-based display.

I've felt the first kind of frustration, but so far I've avoided the second kind.  I keep MS Access and HTML-rendered forms far away from each other.

Comment: It is not strictly "conditional formatting" that I am looking for, but rather how to retrieve the value of a textbox for the current record in a List View.

Comment: I don't understand your goal.  I don't know Custom Web App very well, which may explain why I'm having trouble.  But maybe you should post an image that is marked up, or some other details that can help us.

Comment: I simply want certain records to be highlighted. For example let's say I have a field named MyColor in a table. Then if the value in that field of the current record in the View is "Red", I want the textboxes in the View to be Red.

Answer (score 0):

Conditional Formatting in the List View of Access Web Apps is Available its just way harder than it should be.

1. Input "If Statement" under the "Current Macro" by clicking outside any text box or label then traveling to the top right of the view and you will see the Lightning bolt which allows two options, "On Load" and "On Current". 
   SELECT ON CURRENT
2. Don't forget You will need to set the control back to the original color by using the else. (also, for some reason I have to flip the Colors so where you would think red would go, Put White.

> ```
> Example: 
> IF = "" True Then 
>    White 
> Else 
>    Red
> END IF /DONT ASK ME WHY!
> ```

Summary: your Code is Sound, Just input it under the Views Current Macro Location
This is my first post, i spent DAYS looking for this information and found in the deep google somewhere so i hope this helps you.